# Memory increase non-stop with basic Sails application

Tags: node.js, sails.js

To be short, I've setup a no frontend sails project with a basic controller and hit it with loadtest, the memory keeps increasing and no sign of stablizing. I've read previous posts and have disabled grunt, session, socket, pubsub and etc.

**Setup:**

Sails version: v0.12.3

Node version: v4.4.7

NPM version: v2.15.8

**Reproduce:**

create new sails project

```
sails new Project --no-frontend
```

edit .sailsrc:

```
{
  "generators": {
    "modules": {}
  },

  "hooks": {
    "session": false,
    "sockets": false,
    "pubsub": false,
    "grunt": false,
    "i18n": false
  }
}
```

added controllers/TestController.js:

```
module.exports = {
  hi: function (req, res) {
    return res.send("Hi there!");
  }
};
```

run load test:

```
var loadtest = require('loadtest');

var host = 'http://localhost:1337';

var options = {
    url: host + '/test/hi',
    requestsPerSecond: 50
};

loadtest.loadTest(options, function(error, result)
{
    if (error)
    {
        return console.error('Got an error: %s', error);
    }
    console.log('Tests run successfully: '+result);
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Mars

Comment: do you know how to profile a nodejs application?

Answer (score 3):

1. Take a few heap dumps before, during, and after your load test.
2. Examine in Chrome dev tools by loading the heap dump
3. Report the leak!

https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-heapdump

Also, you could try forcing GC every 60 seconds or something manually by setting a timeout, to see if memory goes down after GC (which means there is not a leak).

node --expose-gc script.js

And then from within the Javascript just do:

```
setTimeout(function(){
     global.gc();
},60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I still cannot figure out what's going on with sails.js after investigating for a month. I end up re-write everything with the basic express framework and I'm glad I did it.